# double vertical tab with content box

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i make this vertical tab that when i click one buton ( tab ) to open another row of tabs and only then to open the content box?
this is almost the result http://jsfiddle.net/2jryD , i could not find the 1.4.2.min.js library to link it.
I think that i should do some changes in the html and js, but i dont know what.... can you help me ?

JS + the libraries

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#textExample").verticaltabs({speed: 500,slideShow: false,activeIndex: 2});
        $("#imageExample").verticaltabs({speed: 1000,slideShow: true,slideShowSpeed: 3000,activeIndex: 0,playPausePos: "topRight"});
    });
```

html

```
<div class="verticalslider" id="textExample">
        <ul class="verticalslider_tabs">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praesent Pulvinar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nunc Adipiscing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Praesent Dapibus</a></li>                        
        </ul>
        <ul class="verticalslider_contents">
         <li>
            <h2>Praesent Pulvinar</h2>
            <p>Praesent pulvinar, lorem nec ullamcorper semper, ipsum erat vestibulum lacus, in sodales lorem mi in leo. Vestibulum et rhoncus tellus. Curabitur mauris enim, vehicula sit amet euismod a, eleifend at dui. Vivamus sollicitudin, nunc pharetra porttitor lobortis, felis odio hendrerit mi, id ultricies urna enim quis lectus. Suspendisse convallis ipsum egestas velit fermentum ac volutpat dui dictum. </p></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit what you are wanting to do? It might be helpful to create a jsfiddle of the code, and then describe what it is that you'd like it to do differently than what it does.

Comment: i am kind of newbie in this domain, it is a project for school, and i have some trouble implementing the jquery libraries in the jsfiddle... this is almost the result http://jsfiddle.net/2jryD/ ( i also used 1.4.2.min.js library, but i did not found a link on web) .... but i want when you click one of the buttons ( tabs ) to open another row of buttons, and only by clicking this ones, they will open a content box

Comment: Don't worry about finding that specific version of jQuery; it's quite old anyway. Your code may need work to do what you want, but it should at least run without errors in jQuery 1.9. This page explains how to include jQuery: http://jquery.com/download/. The easiest way for the current version would be this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I know but my problem is not the implement of jquery, mine is how to make the tab, when i click it to open another row of tabs, and clicking this last ones to open the content box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example is good](http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/), just change the css

```
.mydivContent {
    clear: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 124px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#tab .nav {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[I let the example](http://jsbin.com/izovak/2/edit)

Comment: and if you have another list in one of the items(li) of the first list ? i mean like this : <ul><li>First Buton<ul><li>2 row buton</li></ul></li></ul> .... cause in my projects, some items have second bulets

Comment: you must put it in another tab, changing labels and divs calling javascript function again. As if it were something new the tab-nav and content-tab

Comment: oh! that is just sad, because i found this code premade, i did not do it. i do not know to code in javascript,that is my problem. Could you help me recode it ?

Comment: [link](http://jsbin.com/utaxot/3/edit) this is the solution, you must change the css. remember to vote and accept my answe. [eg](http://goo.gl/tvN61)